# Dataflow Job extracting meta information

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

Let's say I have dataflow job which reads from bucket **a** and writes to BQ table **dataset.tableTest**. Is it possible to extract precise meta information from Dataflow REST API, what source (**a**) and sink (**dataset.tableTest**) is used in dataflow job?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of steps in a Dataflow job using the following command.

```
jobs describe <Job ID> --full
```

Note though that, from Cloud Dataflow's perspective, your job is simply running a set of Beam transforms. It does not group or identify steps based on the functionality (for example, whether the step is a source/sink transform).